# OpenGL - Project a sphere crop onto the tangent plane

Tags: opengl

I am using PyOpenGL to draw a sphere and texture it with a 360 degree image. I want to be able to specify a crop of this sphere's surface and project it onto the corresponding tangent plane.

See

[image]

for an example (image taken from http://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.00919.pdf).

I have two questions:

1. Knowing the UV coordinates of the desired crop, how do I specify the crop in the sphere surface?
2. What is the best way to project this crop into the tangent plane and save the resulting projection?

Comment: Not just a snapshot. The 360 degree image is projected to a plane, so it has the related distortions. I then project it to a sphere. What I need to do is to get a crop and project that crop into the tangent plane. By doing this I'm trying to remove as far as possible of the distortion in that particular piece of the image. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not directly relevant to the question, but I had written a little skybox demo in PyOpenGL that uses a cubemap texture. The code for that can be found [here](https://github.com/AnishN/PySky). It does not use a sphere, but perhaps it might prove helpful since there is not a lot of python + opengl stuff out there. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, @CodeSurgeon!